# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting

Tags: modx

Помогите исправить ошибку на сайте:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ')' in
>   /manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(814) : eval()'d code
>   on line 10

CMS MODx (Evo),  мне неизвестно, что делать в таких случаях и какую информацию следует предоставить.

Comment: название файла и номер строки (814) приведены в сообщении. выложить лучше «с запасом» — код всей функции, отметив номера строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MODX выполняет сниппет хранящийся в базе, но в нем есть ошибка.

Определите какой сниппет используется на странице и исправьте его код.

В админке MODX есть раздел с логами, иногда там написано в каком сниппете ошибка.

Comment: Благодарю! Разобрался, оказалась такая мелочь.